# Why doesn't validation work with this function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to validate a form (it's very simple it just have an input and a button) but my JS code doesn't work.

```js
window.onload = iniciar;

function iniciar() {
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('submit', validar);
}

function validaNombre() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById("nombre");
  if (elemento.value = "") {
    alert("por favor verifica el campo nombre");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validar(e) {
  if (validarNombre()) {
    alert("Se envio el elemento");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET" id="miForm">
  <br>
  <label>Name*</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="b1" id="nombre" maxlength="32" name="name">
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Registrar">
  <br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `submit` event goes with the form, not the button.

You also had a typo in the function name `validaNombre`. And you have to use `==` to compare, not `=`.

```js
window.onload = iniciar;

function iniciar() {
  document.getElementById("miForm").addEventListener('submit', validar);
}

function validarNombre() {
  var elemento = document.getElementById("nombre");
  if (elemento.value == "") {
    alert("por favor verifica el campo nombre");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function validar(e) {
  if (validarNombre()) {
    alert("Se envio el elemento");
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="GET" id="miForm">
  <br>
  <label>Name*</label><br>
  <input type="text" class="b1" id="nombre" maxlength="32" name="name">
  <br><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Registrar">
  <br>
</form>
```